# C++ find strings in input and use operators

Tags: c++, string, operators

I've been trying to find a way to use a string input in cmd and have the output of a cmd happen as long as those strings are present. Below are some code that sort of works but still has some problems.

```
    if (text.find("floor") && text.find("knife")!=std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "Knife and Floor test" << std::endl;
    }
    if (text.find("knife") !=std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "just knife" << std::endl;
    }
```

the above does work. Kind of. Typing in floor does not give a response which is good. "floor knife" outputs "Kife and Floor test" which is what I want. but typing in just "knife" gives **both** "Knife and Floor test" and "just knife."

```
        if (text.find("can") !=std::string::npos)
        {
            if (text.find("elizabeth") !=std::string::npos)
            {
                if (text.find("you") !=std::string::npos)
                {
                    std::cout << "1912" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if (text.find("elizabeth") !=std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << "just elizabeth" << std::endl;
        }
```

Above works as well, but it gives a similar problem. Though "1912" does output when only "elizabeth" "can" and "you" are present, "just elizabeth" outputs as well.

In the end, my goal is to be able to control what runs with what is inputted using operators, if that's possible. If operands are the wrong way to go, than what should I use?

**Pseudo Code of goal**

```
if((("word"||"thisword")&&("this")) !=std::string::npos)

     {

      run

     }

or

if(("thisword") && ("thisotherword") !=std::string::npos)

     {

      run

     }

or

if(("thisword") || ("thisotherword") !=std::string::npos)

     {

      run

     }
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: `text.find("floor") && text.find("knife")!=std::string::npos` This isn't right. You need to compare both to npos seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
    if ( text.find( "floor" ) != std::string::npos && 
         text.find( "knife" ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "Knife and Floor test" << std::endl;
    }
    else if ( text.find( "knife" ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "just knife" << std::endl;
    }

//...

        if ( text.find( "can" ) != std::string::npos )
        {
            if ( text.find( "elizabeth" ) != std::string::npos )
            {
                if ( text.find( "you" ) != std::string::npos )
                {
                    std::cout << "1912" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ( text.find( "elizabeth" ) != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout << "just elizabeth" << std::endl;
        }


if( ( text.find( "this" ) != std:;string::npos &&
      ( text.find("word" ) != std::string::npos  ||
        text.find( "thisword" )!= std::string::npos ) )

{

      run

}
```

or

```
if ( text.find( "thisword" ) != std::string::npos && 
     text.find( "thisotherword" ) != std::string::npos )
{

      run

}
```

or

```
if ( text.find( "thisword" ) != std::string::npos || 
     text.find( "thisotherword" ) !=std::string::npos )
{

      run

}
```

The first if statement can be rewritten the following way

```
if ( text.find( "knife" ) != std::string::npos )
{
    if ( text.find( "floor" ) != std::string::npos ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Knife and Floor test" << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "just knife" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example is exactly what I was looking for! Hate how it was so simple! Thank you!

Comment: Fantastic. Will I need to keep the "if else" in mind when using strings more than once, such as the examples with knife?

Answer (score 0):

> typing in just "knife" gives both "Knife and Floor test" and "just
>   knife."

Well, what does this:

```
if (text.find("floor") && text.find("knife")!=std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "Knife and Floor test" << std::endl;
}
```

actually mean? It means that if the search for "knife" does not return `string::npos`, and the search for "floor" returns *something that evaluates to true* (such as, say, `string::npos`), then print "Knife and Floor test". This is the reason that Vlad's alteration of your code works properly.

As for this:

> Though "1912" does output when only "elizabeth" "can" and "you" are
>   present, "just elizabeth" outputs as well.

The reason that sticking an `else if` in place of `if` is because your code, as it was, was treating this section:

```
if (text.find("can") !=std::string::npos)
{
    if (text.find("elizabeth") !=std::string::npos)
    {
        if (text.find("you") !=std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << "1912" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

and this section:

```
if (text.find("elizabeth") !=std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "just elizabeth" << std::endl;
}
```

as independent tests. That is, without the `else`, it didn't matter if the upper segment evaluated to true and did its own thing, because the lower segment was going to evaluate *no matter what happened above*. Sticking in an `else` says "test this conditional statement only if the above associated `if` did **not** evaluate to true".

I hope this helps you understand *why* the proposed solution is correct.

Comment: As to why things don't work, is just as informative as to why it does. Thank you! Will screen print for notes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some helper functions to make it easier to test of a string matches one of something in a list of string (`find_any()`), or matches all items in the list (`find_all()`).

```
    if (find_all(text1, "knife", "floor")) {
        std::cout << "knife and floor test pass 1\n";
    }

    if (!find_all(text2, "knife", "floor")) {
        std::cout << "knife and floor test pass 2\n";
    }

    if (!find_all(text3, "knife", "floor")) {
        std::cout << "knife and floor test pass 3\n";
    }

    if (find_any(text2, "knife", "floor")) {
        if (findx(text2, "knife")) {
            std::cout << "knife or floor found knife\n";
        }
    }

    if (find_any(text3, "knife", "floor")) {
        if (findx(text3, "floor")) {
            std::cout << "knife or floor found floor\n";
        }
    }
```

`findx()` is a simple helper function to provide a boolean result for you:

```
bool findx (std::string haystack, std::string s) {
    return haystack.find(s) != haystack.npos;
}
```

`find_all()` and `find_any()` could be implemented with variable argument template functions, but there are other ways too:

```
enum FIND_X { FIND_ALL, FIND_ANY };

template <typename... Strings>
bool find_any (std::string haystack, Strings... args) {
    return find_x<FIND_ANY, Strings...>(haystack, args...);
}

template <typename... Strings>
bool find_all (std::string haystack, Strings... args) {
    return find_x<FIND_ALL, Strings...>(haystack, args...);
}

template <FIND_X, typename T>
bool find_x (std::string haystack, T s) {
    return findx(haystack, s);
}

template <FIND_X OP, typename T, typename... Strings>
bool find_x (std::string haystack, T s, Strings... args) {
    if (haystack.find(s) != haystack.npos) {
        if (OP == FIND_ANY) return true;
    } else {
        if (OP == FIND_ALL) return false;
    }
    return find_x<OP, Strings...>(haystack, args...);
}
```

[A live demo.](http://ideone.com/kq20MB)

Comment: Interesting. Makes things simpler and more precise. Lots of ways I can use this. I'll have to experiment and find ways to really take advantage of it all. Big help! Thank you!